# Spotfire Automation

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to automate the publish of dxp file to the server. What I want to achieve is build a command line tool, user navigates to the dxp file and runs a command (let's say publish), this should save the file to the library without opening spotfire client (something similar to running spotfire in Headless mode).

I got to know that Spotfire Automation Services can be of some help in this task, but I have never used the automation services and don't know how to install or find the automation services module. Any help or direction is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Automation Services is a licensed framework from TIBCO that lets you automate several tasks including Open or Save analysis to library, replace or remap data sources, run alerts etc.

But if your sole requirement is to publish analysis to library then use the import-library-content on command line, or save it in a batch file and use IronPython to trigger that as using button from the DXP.

See [API docs of import-library-content](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-1A7D1145-AB93-40FF-9E28-070EB76212C5.html) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

you can check Google for Automation Services and see more details on its capabilities, but I'm pretty sure your use case is covered. Spotfire does not offer this feature out of the box (except maybe using the admin command tool, but that'd only be for admins).

your organization will need to buy a license for AS, since it's a separate product in the Spotfire suite. talk to your TIBCO rep or send me a PM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Automation Services for this. Automation Services needs to be licensed from TIBCO, but it provides a framework that will allow you to create job.xml files which specify a list of tasks for Automation Services to execute.  You can then submit the job file to a web service when you want the tasks to be executed.